# Disabled button on multiple ternary operator in Angular 2

Tags: angular, button, angular2-forms

I might be doing something wrong here , but could not able to resolve this issue.

I am trying to disable button with two forms validation 
like

```
this.dailyFlag = true;
this.monthlyFlag = false;
```

and having form

```
<form (submit)='pushData()' #dailyForm="ngForm">...</form>  
<form (submit)='pushData()' #monthlyForm="ngForm">...</form>  
<button disabled='--- saveral condition as below--' >
```

> ```
> If (dailyFlag && monthlyFlg) then check both forms sholud be valid 
> else
> if(daliFlag) then checkFor dailyForm valid only  else false
> if(monthlyFlag) then check For monthlyForm valid only else false
> ```

**Copy below code to this below plunker code to execute and check
https://plnkr.co/edit/JQjLMJiohgOJ8Mf6xbgP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This will disable the button if one the form is invalid.

```
[disabled] = "!dailyForm.valid || !monthlyForm.valid"
```

*// disable true if dailyForm is NOT Valid or monthlyForm is NOT Valid*

Comment: yes but forms are shown / hidden based on flag like dailyFlag and monthlyFlag. So if I put the above condition it will mandatory check for both forms validation which not a case

Comment: Use [hidden] = "!dailyForm"

Answer (score 0):

This condition should work

```
[disabled] ="(!dailyForm.valid && dailyFlag) || (!monthlyForm.valid && monthlyFlag)"
```

EDIT corrected typos

Comment: Sorry, It had typos, did you correct them before testing?

Comment: Ah, i found an error in your setup:   `dailyFlag: true;
  monthlyFlag: true;` should be `dailyFlag= true;
  monthlyFlag= true;`

Comment: And i forgot .valid on monthlyForm